# python find if each element of a string list contains any of another string list

Tags: python, list

suppose I have two string list:

```
a=['ab','ac','ad']
b=['abcd','baa','bacd','bbaa']
```

and I want to know if each element of list b has any of strings in a as its substring. The correct result should be: [True,False,True,False]. How do I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [any(i in j for i in a) for j in b]
[True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: I am a pyhton n00b, can you explain this to me like I am 5

Comment: @alex `i in j for i in a` generates a series of Boolean objects (`i in j` which checks if `i` exist in `j`) and `any` does what's explained in documentation on those objects and returns one Boolean object in result. This process repeats with `for j in b`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
[any([i in j for i in a]) for j in b]
```

would do the trick.